# Understanding category sub categories and how it works

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

(**Working on mysql**)

I have this category-subcategory table (The adjacency model)

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Which works good for up to the first level.

Example:

```
Computer > Software
Computer > Monitor
Computer > Printer
```

But what if the the sub-category to is to be divided into more sub-categories to make more sense or easy naviagtion like

[image]

My question:

1. What is further division of a sub-category called? Sub sub category, sub category to nth, I ask because I do not know what to search google for when it comes to sub category further having more categories.
2. How do you solve this problem, need for further sub sub category? I read somewhere that after the sub-category, which in this case is the monitor, software, printer you use product tags for further division ... this confused me, If this is how it is to be done can you show me lil example.
3. What exactly is the right way.

Comment: Read this article, http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: @Chintan7027, thank you. Looks good, I'll good thought it.

Comment: I have the impression that your issue is more about semantics than design...

Comment: @ThomasG, nope, its both, semantics alone wont help. I'd like to know the design or else the semantic wont help. See question 2 and 3.

Comment: The adjacency list model you presented can represent a much deeper level of nesting than you present.  Your question number 1 above seems like a question purely of semantics and not one of design.

Comment: The answer to question 3 is 42.

Comment: @WalterMitty, Hi, yups the adjacency model can go much deeper. The 1st question was about semantics but the other two were regarding the model. Answer to 3 is 42? I did not get this.

Comment: 42 is the universal answer.  Disregard.

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean by "about the model"

Comment: @WalterMitty, I did not get what you say. Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 1):

I designed the same DB structure for categories in my classifieds portal. And I achieved the nth level of subcategories in one table using the following design.

**CATEGORIES TABLE**

```
id | category_title | parent_id
1  | fruit          | null
2  | orange         | 1
3  | apple          | 1
4  | orange-child   | 2
```

The parent id will be null for parent categories and will have ID of a parent category if it is a child category. The orange is parent and child at the same time. Because, orange is the child of the fruit and parent of the orange-child category. This way you can get the hierarchical structure of categories.